# Using xpath on javascript console

Tags: javascript, xpath, console

Hi I want to get someid's content by using xpath.
my xpath:

```
//*[someid"]/div[1]/div/div[1]
```

code that doesn't even run:

```
alert($x(//*[someid"]/div[1]/div/div[1]));
```

error I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Comment: Have you tried quoting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unmatched quote in your expression - a typo? Apart from that, use

```
$x('//*["someid"]/div[1]/div/div[1]')
```

in the browser console, for instance the Chrome Dev tools.

It strikes me as odd that there should be a `Unexpected token }` in a line of code where `}` does not even occur.